# Authomatically focusing on input and press enter

Tags: javascript

I have an input with id "test". I want to paste in console some text (= script), that will automatically focus on input and press enter.

How can I realize this?

I tried `document.getElementById("test").value += "\n"`, but nothing was happen. I also tried search on the internet, but I found nothing..

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
if (event.key === "Enter") {
event.preventDefault();
console.log("Enter Pressed!")
}});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

don't forget that, when you use `addEventListener` for an `input`, it just work when you `focus` on it.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but this code will show me when I press enter, and I kindly asked to share with me code, that will press enter automatically, without use mechanics

Comment: You want to press enter automatically?
For example, after document in ready?

Comment: Yes, after document in ready

Comment: Can you explain what you want exactly? I think it might have a better solution for your business